# Log out button causes crash?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android app with a simple login and log out app from this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

BUt logging out causes the app to crash
Logcat report

```
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 1926
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.learn2crack.tab.Attendance$1.onClick(Attendance.java:53)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-26 04:53:03.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

function for logging out

```
SessionManager session;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
public void logoutUser(){



   // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Class that calls the function

```
public class Attendance extends Fragment{
    SessionManager session;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


        View attendance = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attedance, container, false);





        final ImageButton logoutbtn = (ImageButton)attendance.findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn);




        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                    // Clear the session data
                    // This will clear all session data and 
                    // redirect user to LoginActivity
                    session.logoutUser();
                }
            });
        return attendance;}


}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException -  I think it says all you need

Comment: what is session and where you initialize ?

Comment: not the right place to ask

Comment: I think you have not initialized your `SessionManager` class

Comment: What's line Attendance.java:53?

Comment: I have initialized session I didn't add the code by mistake.

Comment: May be your `_context`  variable is null.

Comment: You have *Declared* Session. Not *Initialized*. You will need to add `session = new SessionManager();` before you use session.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your SessionManager Class that's the reason why you are getting NPE:

```
public class Attendance extends Fragment{
    SessionManager session;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View attendance = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attedance, container, false);

        session = new SessionManager(); //<-- Add this

        final ImageButton logoutbtn = (ImageButton)attendance.findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn);
        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Clear the session data
                    // This will clear all session data and 
                    // redirect user to LoginActivity
                    session.logoutUser();
                }
            });
        return attendance;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I actually did initialize it. I wasn't able to include it in the post

Comment: where did you initialize  it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you haven't initialize your `SessionManager`  class. So initialize  it in `onCreateView()` method. Like

```
session = new SessionManager();
```

and if it has a Context then this one

```
session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
```

Comment: thank you for the response but I have initialized it I just didin't include it int the post by mistake

Comment: Check is your _context variable null??